# DEVELOPER ERROR for Android login React Native Google sign in

Tags: android, react-native, google-signin

I want to make a Google login without Firebase, but I got this error. How can I resolve this problem?

I so confused with this error. I followed the tutorial, but I had this problem.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'
    import { GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton } from '@react-native-community/google-signin'
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: '914165873551-tds2ncvh2ebb7shbca8ag7cjnh53d73t.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      offlineAccess: true
    })
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          userGoogleInfo: {},
          loaded: false
        }
      }
      signIn = async () => {
        try {
          await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices()
          const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
          this.setState({
            userGoogleInfo: userInfo,
            loaded: true
          })
        }
        catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message)
        }
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <GoogleSigninButton
              onPress={this.signIn}
              size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
              color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
              style={{ width: 200, height: 100 }}
            />
            {this.state.loaded ?
              <View>
                <Text>{this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.name}</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.email}</Text>
                <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: this.state.userGoogleInfo.user.photo }}></Image>
              </View> :
              <Text>Not SignIn</Text>
            }
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

    export default App
```

I want to make a Google login without Firebase, but I got this error. How can I resolve this problem?

I so confused with this error. I followed the tutorial, but I had this problem.

Comment: Can you be more spesific about the error?

Comment: i dont know because the error just like that